# Oracle update using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need to convert my `update` Ms SQL Server query for Oracle

I have two tables:

```
Table1(id int, SaveId int, ChangeId int)
Table2(id int, smSaved int, boldId int)
```

The query is:

```
UPDATE
  Table1
Set 
  SaveId=tbl.smSaved
FROM
  Table1 tbl1
join Table2 tbl on tbl1.ChangeId=tbl.boldId
```

In MsSql everything works fine, but when I'm trying to run it in Oracle thats doesn't works. I can't figure out whats wrong with it.

Can anybody explain me what I need to change?

Comment: The MS SQL Server UPDATE with FROM is product specific, and not included in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET SaveId = 
    (SELECT tbl.saved FROM table2 tbl
    WHERE tbl.boldId = table1.ChangeId)
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT tbl.saved FROM table2 tbl
    WHERE tbl.boldId = table1.ChangeId
)
```

The first part of query update SaveId with value of tbl.saved (I suppose you have only one row of table2 linked with table1.

The second part (exists) guarantee you have a correspond between two table (if you add exists you put NULL where not exists row in table2)

Answer (score 1):

You are may to use update with subquery same MS SQL. In Oracle its look like:

```
UPDATE (SELECT t1.savedId t1_saved
         , t2.smsaved t2_saved
      FROM table1 t1
         , table2 t2
     WHERE t1.changeid = t2.boldid)
SET t1_saved = t2_saved
```